# creating database in sqlite with cordova

Tags: javascript, android, html, sqlite, cordova

this my index.html i don't know where is the problem but this code doesn't create for me database any help please or remarque can be useful.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
                var db = window.openDatabase("test", "2.0", "Test DB", 1000000);    
                alert(window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "Test DB", 1000000) +' kolll')
                db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB); 
                }

        // create table
        function populateDB(tx) {
         tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table');
         tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (ROLLING INT, firstname text, lastname text, numphone text)');
         tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('adam', 'smith', '887884')");
         tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('david', 'ooo', '15588')");
        }
        function errorCB(err) {
                  console.log("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);

        alert('DATABASE NOT CREATED ');
        }
        // Success error callback

        function successCB() {
                    alert('DATABASE CREATED ');

        } 
</script>

thank you
```

Answer (score 0):

you are creating the database twice with different versions (2.0 and 1.0).

```
1.var db = window.openDatabase("test", "2.0", "Test DB", 1000000);

2.alert(window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "Test DB", 1000000) +' kolll')
```

you need to change the alert call inside  `onDeviceReady()`. e.g

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    alert('Calling onDeviceReady');

    var db = window.openDatabase("test", "2.0", "Test DB", 1000000);    
    alert( 'window.openDatabase called' + ' kolll');

    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB); 

}
```

The above changes hopefully should create the database and the tables.